# Como publicar uma biblioteca TypeScript no NPM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, biblioteca

Configurei o `package.json` com as propriedades `main` e `types`:

```
{
    "name": "idb2promise",
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "description": "TypeScript library to manage IndexedDB Storage",
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "files": [ "./dist" ],
    "scripts": { [...] },
    "keywords": [ [...] ],
    "author": "Guilherme Costamilam",
    "license": "MIT",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/Costamilam/IDB2Promise.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Costamilam/IDB2Promise/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://costamilam.github.io/IDB2Promise/",  
    "dependencies": { },
    "devDependencies": { [...] }
}
```

Configurei o `tsconfig.json` com a propriedade `declaration` como `true`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./dist",
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "lib": [ "es2015.promise"],
    "include": [ "src/**/*.ts" ],
    "exclude": [ "src/test.ts" ]
}
```

No `.npmignore` coloquei o código TypeScript, os arquivos de testes e configuração

```
src
coverage
test
karma.conf.js
rollup.config.js
tsconfig.json
test.tsconfig.json
```

E no `/src/index.ts` exporto as partes públicas

```
export * from './object-store';
export * from './intefaces/request';
export * from './intefaces/request-event';
export * from './intefaces/async-cursor';
```

Faço o build com o `tsc -b` e publico com o comando `npm publish`

A estrutura da pasta `dist`:

```
|- dist
    |- <file>.js/.map.js/.d.ts
    |- util
        |- <file>.js/.map.js/.d.ts
    |- interfaces
        |- <file>.js/.map.js/.d.ts
```

O `/dist/index.d.ts` é igual ao `/src/index.ts` acima

O arquivo `/dist/index.js` gerado:

```
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__export(require("./object-store"));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Em outro projeto, instalo como dependência:

```
npm i idb2promise
```

Ao tentar importar os componentes

```
import { ObjectStore } from 'idb2promise';
```

Recebo o erro

> Cannot find module 'idb2promise'. ts(2307)

Porém, se eu importar usando o caminho relativo até o `index`, funciona como o esperado

```
import { ObjectStore } from './node_modules/idb2promise/dist/index';
```

Como importar o que é exportado pelo index apenas pelo nome do pacote em vez do caminho relativo?

Comment: Opa dá uma olhada: https://cameronnokes.com/blog/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm/

Comment: Seu pacote é esse?https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb2promise

Comment: @Marconi obrigado pelo link, já tinha visto esse, mas vou reolhar. Sim é esse mesmo

Comment: @Marconi revi como foi feito no link e o repositório no GitHub, mas, aparentemente, faço a mesma coisa, não sei porque não está funcionando. Não conhecia o `npm link`, vai ser de grande ajuda para testar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro que você está tendo quando importa o módulo pelo TypeScript:

> ```
> Cannot find module 'idb2promise'. ts(2307)
> ```

Se dá tendo em vista que o TypeScript está tentando resolver o módulo usando a nova especificação de módulos do ECMAScript 2015 (vulgo ES6), e o seu módulo, `idb2promise` *não exporta*, no `package.json`, um módulo que se adeque a essa nova especificação no campo `module`, exportando somente o módulo CommonJS, no campo `main`.

Em suma, você precisará gerar dois arquivos "principais" que importarão o resto da sua biblioteca: um para o CommonJS e outro para a nova especificação.

O compilador do TypeScript, `tsc`, contudo, não possui um meio fácil para fazer esse tipo de coisa. Passei por um problema parecido durante a migração para TypeScript de uma singela biblioteca que fiz, [`yiq`](https://github.com/lffg/yiq/tree/v3.0.1/src).

Basicamente, você deve ter três tipos de arquivos definidos no seu `package.json`:

- `main`: O módulo que será requerido pelo *cliente* que estiver utilizando CommonJS, como em um ambiente Node.js;
- `module`: O módulo que será importado pelo *cliente* que estiver usando a nova especificação de [módulos do ES6<sup>[EN]</sup>](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html#ecmascript-modules);
- `types` (ou `typings`): Será usado pelo TypeScript.

Desse modo, para facilitar a sua vida, ao invés de utilizar o compilador padrão do TypeScript, `tsc`, sugiro que você use *bundlers* como o [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org), e utilizar um plugin como o `rollup-plugin-typescript2` para a integração com o TypeScript. Deixarei abaixo duas opções — a primeira que utilizará o Rollup e a segunda, o `tsc`.

## Fazer a compilação usando o [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org)

É sem dúvidas a opção mais fácil e a que eu mais priorizarei, já que o *bundler* fará todo o "trabalho pesado" para você. Basta instalar o `rollup` e `rollup-plugin-typescript2` e criar um arquivo de configuração `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
  // O `entry` do seu pacote:
  input: 'src/idb2promise.ts',

  plugins: [
    typescript({
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      clean: true
    })
  ],
  output: [
    { file: 'build/idb2promise.cjs.js', format: 'cjs' },
    { file: 'build/idb2promise.js', format: 'es' }

    // Note que o arquivo de declaração do TypeScript terá o nome
    // baseado no `input`. Nesse caso, será `idb2promise.d.ts`.
  ]
};
```

Note que definimos dois arquivos de saída em `output`. Um deles será o módulo CommonJS, que exportaremos no campo `main` do `package.json`; e outro que será o módulo da especificação do ES6, que será exportado no campo `main`. A declaração, por fim, terá o nome baseado no `input`. No exemplo acima, teremos `idb2promise.d.ts`, que também será colocada no diretório `build`.

Então, teremos algo assim no `package.json`:

```js
{
  [...]

  "main": "build/lisdir-cjs.js",
  "module": "build/lisdir.mjs",
  "types": "build/lisdir.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  }
  
  [...]
}
```

Um exemplo dessa abordagem pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/lffg/yiq).

## Fazer a compilação usando o `tsc`

Basta criar dois arquivos em TypeScript que serão usados para exportar a sua biblioteca. Por exemplo, `src/idb2promise.cjs.ts` e `src/idb2promise.ts`. No

Para exportar a versão que suportará a nova especificação de módulos do ECMAScript 2015, criaremos o arquivo `src/idb2promise.ts`:

```js
//# src/idb2promise.ts

import { ib2promise } from './lib/idb2promise';

export default ib2promise;

export * from './lib/other-stuff';
```

E por fim, para exportar um módulo CommonJS, criaremos o arquivo `src/idb2promise.cjs.ts`:

```js
//# src/idb2promise.cjs.ts

import { idb2promise } from './lib/color-yiq';
import { otherStuff1, otherStuff2 } from './lib/other-stuff';

exports.otherStuff1 = otherStuff1;
exports.otherStuff2 = otherStuff2;

// Export "default":
export = colorYiq;
```

Note acima que usamos a declaração `export =` para exportar o módulo usando CommonJS. Conforme [consta na documentação do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require), em Inglês:

> TypeScript supports `export =` to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow. The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.

E por fim, basta incluir no `package.json` os três arquivos "de exportação" que criamos — o compatível com ES6, o compatível com CommonJS e as definições geradas pelo TypeScript.

Um exemplo dessa abordagem pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/lffg/yiq/tree/v3.0.1/src).

---

P.S.: Essa resposta é uma versão estendida de uma [resposta do StackOverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56402067/7445826). Apesar de outrora ter me ajudado, hoje em dia considero o Rollup uma opção mais simples do que utilizar o `tsc` e a declaração `export =`. :)

Comment: cara, não precisa publicar com o rollup, eu já publiquei lib assim e não deu problema, é outro problema aí...
se a biblioteca só possuir um "main" no package.json, ele vai importar como commonjs.
o que indica que a biblioteca quer ser consumida como es-modules é o uso da flag "module" no package.json

Comment: Em nenhum momento disse que era necessário usar o Rollup. Foi apenas uma recomendação. Já publiquei 3 bibliotecas usando TypeScript, e até este momento, utilizar o Rullup foi a melhor forma que eu encontrei. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import * as idb from 'idb2promise'
```

Isso funcionou.

*Provavelmente* colocar `esModuleInterop: true` no seu tsconfig resolva o problema. Daí também vai poder importar via `import idb from 'idb2promise'` (sintaxe de import defailt).

**História**

Basicamente, o `module.exports` do commonjs e o `export default` do es-modules são coisas diferentes. O export default é literalmente um export nomeado de nome "default". Canonicamente, não deveria poder se importar commonjs com a sintaxe de import default.

Um dia o pessoal do babel resolveu fazer uma gambizinha pra que usar `import nome from 'lib'` também funcione com o export global commonjs (o `module.exports =`). Essa gambizinha, no TS é ativada com a `esModuleInterop`.

Sobre como funciona o webpack:

- Ele procura a chave "module" no package.json pra importar uma lib como es-modules. O es-modules permite "tree-shaking";
- Se não encontrar, ele procura a chave "main", neste caso a lib será interpretada como "commonjs";

Caso você queira publicar es-module, o mais correto seria você publicar os dois. Eu recomendo você experimentar o [TSDX](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx) pra isso, que é uma configuração de rollup pronta.